# How to extract the percentage from the array

Tags: php

How to extract the percentage from the array
The result is as follows: 41 - 16 - 8 - 33
Total is 98, not 100
How to make it = 100

```
$sum = array(500.36,200.32,100.09,400);
$total =  array_sum($sum);
foreach($sum as $val){
    $st = intval($val / $total * 100 );
    echo $st.'<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using intval(). you should use round() with the precision of 2. you are skipping fractions by converting answer to integer. PHP is using floor method so your answer is losing fractions. here is the code

```
$sum = array(500.36,200.32,100.09,400);
$total =  array_sum($sum);
foreach($sum as $val){
    $st = round($val / $total * 100, 2 );
    echo $st.'<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason is: precision :)
With intval() you skip the decimals. so 41+16+8+33 is REALLY 98.

If you add them with 2 decimals:
41.66 + 16.68 + 8.33 + 33.31 = 99.98

If you do round() instead of intval() you'll round the values so it'll be more close statistically. you'll get: 42 + 17 + 8 + 33 = 100

BUT! if you want to make sure the sum is 100, than you should pick one number (I suggest the biggest one) to calculate that as: 100 - sum(the rest).

Answer (score 2):

Rounding!

Take the number `500.36`;

`500.36 / 1200.77 * 100`:
`41,669928463`

Since you're using `intval` those deciamals are lost, remove `intval` to keep the decimals, then you'll reach 100 total.

Consider an extra variable to check this;

```php
<?php
$sum = array(500.36,200.32,100.09,400);
$total =  array_sum($sum);
$test = 0;
foreach($sum as $val){
    $st = $val / $total * 100;
    echo $st.'<br>';
    $test += $st;
}
echo $test;
```

```
41.66992846257
16.682628646618
8.3354847306312
33.311958160181
100
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY3LCsIwEEX38xWzCLTVUMf6AEmrnyKxRLKoJCRREPHbYx7O5sI9Z2astjGOF6stMP984ITSOfluD0T97siHHAPfpqAT3xN1AlgwQS7JrOo1rbV5tyDlQyIk4G6ckrMuBKVH9pJL9wFMw4qTC9zg/9oK0w9RsJq1yU7fjDd3bmpZL6@nDAR8oUq5FDH@AA)

Answer (score 1):

If you make an `intval` to the result you cut the last values.

Without `intval` you can see the problem.

```
41.66992846257
16.682628646618
8.3354847306312
33.311958160181
```

So work with that numbers or round it on 2 decimal numbers.

```
$st = number_format($val / $total * 100, 2, '.', '');
```

something like this.